# Go back to previous page with back button not working

Tags: android

Pardon me, if this question had been asked too many times before. But I have been trying to solve it for a while and tried all the solutions but nothing seems to work for me. Can you please point me what I'm missing here?
When I press the back button on the mobile, it exits the app instead of going to the back page of the webView.
I'll really appreciate your help on what I'm doing wrong here.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private WebView myWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please check previous activity if there’s finish method called any where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement in `onCreate` defines a *local variable* named `myWebView` that hides the instance variable with the same name:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

So, the instance variable  will have a `null` value and `onBackPressed` is likely throwing a `NullPointerException`.

Try changing that statement to this:

```
myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, it solves the problem and it's working perfectly fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mainView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if ((keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                if(webView!=null)
                {
                  if(webView.canGoBack())
                  {
                    webView.goBack();
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```